# Can you eat dock leaves? How can they be prepared?

Tags: cooking, plants, foraging

Are dock leaves/rumex edible? They're on of the most common plants we see in the UK (that and stinging nettles) and I find myself wondering how if I could eat them. I've been told before that you should chew them before applying them to a stinging nettle, so they're not poisonous.

Are they tasty? How would you prepare them?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumex_obtusifolius) says yes, can't say I've ever tried it though.

Comment: I've seen dock leaves used as a flavor enhancing wrap for cooking fish, though not as a food in and of itself. However the stinging nettles are one of the best forage foods out there.

Comment: @ThatIdiot interesting....[How do you eat nettles?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9171/how-do-you-eat-nettles) :)

Comment: @nivag This seems to be more relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorrel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rumex includes both sorrels and docks. The sorrels are generally more widely eaten. You can eat all of them, although they're pretty acid. Sliced finely with other salad greens, they add some bite. You can also wilt them down as you would spinach for a risotto or soup. http://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/rice-recipes/a-beautiful-sorrel-risotto-with-crumbled-goat-s-cheese/

Like Swiss chard, they're high in oxalic acid and too much of that can lead to kidney stones. Many vegetables contain oxalic acid, so it's just something to keep in balance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalic_acid